# Contains method not working

Tags: java

Can you please tell me why in below code contains not working:

```
String str=
        "/XYZ1/Test3-NV28"+
        "/678/13855497776650XB"+
        "/123/";

if ("XYZ".contains(str))

        System.out.println("yes");
else
    System.out.println("no");
    }
```

RP

Comment: You are looking for the other way around `if (str.contains("XYZ"))`. `str` contains "XYZ" but "XYZ" does not contain `str`.

Comment: edited my question.not correct ZouXZou, i tried that one also . if i say str.contains("XYZ") it returns true.

Comment: `str` does contain `XYZ` (`"/XYZ1/Test3-NV28"`), so it's normal that contains returns true. You should read the doc of [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) : _"Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values."_

Comment: So how to resolve my issue,i want to see only specific work existing withing that string.

Comment: What do you mean by _"i want to see only specific work existing withing that string"_ ?

Comment: specific word this case only "XYZ" present within the string or not.if input is XYZ1 then it should return false. is there any api method present to dermine?

Comment: All depends or your String str. If str does not contains "XYZ1", then `str.contains("XYZ1")` will return false. If it does not answer your question, please edit it by adding some examples.

Comment: incoming string contains "XYZ1". str.contains("XYZ") returns true instead of false.

Comment: But why should this returns false ? XYZ is present in XYZ1. That's the normal behaviour of contains.

Comment: ok i understand. Is there any method in api to check exact word with in string? or any other way i can achieve this.

Comment: I suggest you to go through the doc and see what will fits your needs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 3):

You are using the [`Yoda style condition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) in a wrong way. You  have to use it as

```
if (str.contains("XYZ")) {

}
```

For furthur clarification

```
 String x= "test";
    if (x.contains("est")) {  //true
        System.out.println("true");
    }
 if(x.contains("set")){  //false
     System.out.println("false");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

change this `if ("XYZ".contains(str))` to `if (str.contains("XYZ"))`

you are searching if `XYZ` is present in `String str` or not

From the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

*Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.*

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ("XYZ".contains(str))
```

To

```
if (str.contains("XYZ"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
str.contains("XYZ")
```

because `str` contains `"XYZ"` but not the `XYZ` contains `str`

**contains** method name itself says the meaning of the method...

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
if ("XYZ".contains(str))
```

to

```
if (str.contains("XYZ"))
```

because `str` contains `"XYZ"`. whereas `"XYZ"` does not contains `str`
Here is [Java Doc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 0):

If we have two strings and we want to compare them using contains method, the string that is contained must be the subset of original String.
i.e

```
 String originalString="Africa is a continent";
    System.oout.println(originalString.contains("Africa"))
     ///true, will be printed because Africa is in 
                                 ///the originalString
       }
   System.out.println("Africa".contains(OriginalString))// it will print false 

    }
```